# ListView Is deleting Wrong Item

Tags: react-native

I this is a possible duplicate question, but everything appears correct to me. My function does delete an item, but it deletes the wrong one. When I console.log to inspect the of array of objects,  the item I selected is no longer present. With the new object, I then set the state.  Here is my code:

```
     export default class MainApp extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
              damping: 1 - 0.6,
              tension: 400,
              dataBlob: [],
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}),
            };

          }

         componentDidMount() {

        fetch('http://54.152.253.14/barbershop/appointmentHelper.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          this.state.dataBlob = responseData;
          this.setState({
              dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.dataBlob),
              isLoading: false,
            });
        })
        .done();
      }

       deleteItem(rowId){
   console.log(rowId);
   this.state.dataBlob.splice(rowId,1);
   console.log(this.state.dataBlob);
   this.setState({
   dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.dataBlob),
   })
  }
  fetchData() {

  }

  renderList = (dataObj,sectionID,rowId) => {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Row damping={this.state.damping} tension={this.state.tension} onPress={()=>this.deleteItem(rowId)}>
          <View style={styles.rowContent}>
            <View style={styles.rowIcon} />
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.rowTitle}>{dataObj.service}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.rowSubtitle}>Drag the row left and right</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Row>



      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
           <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(data, sectionID, rowID) => this.renderList(data, sectionID, rowID)}
            style={styles.listView}

            />
           );
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I feel like I missing some conceptual idea about list-view and really looking forward to improving my understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my render function to this resolved my issue:

```
render() {
    return (
           <ListView
            key={this.state.dataBlob}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(data, sectionID, rowID) => this.renderList(data, sectionID, rowID)}
            style={styles.listView}

            />
           );
  }
```

Basically, adding a key to keep track of unique items in my list is what saved me. Hopefully, this provides someone else help in the future.